# Kingfisher retry on demand

Tags: swift, swiftui, kingfisher

I am trying to implement an on demand retry for a KFImage in SwiftUI.
My KF image looks like this

```
KFImage(icon)
                .attachPlaceholderAndErrorView(onError: { _ in
                    isFailed = true
                })
                .retry(RetryHandler(shouldRetry: $shouldRetry))
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .isVisible(condition)
```

attachPlaceholderAndErrorView is a custom modifier that attaches a placeholder progressview, an on failure callback and an failure image.
Basically I was expecting to pass a binding to a RetryHandler that is a struct conforming to RetryStrategy and fire the retry function every time I want... but this is not working as that. Does anyone have any ideea?

Comment: Usually a retry policy is used when after making the request, it fails. It's not, what I guess you are looking for a "relaunch all requests that have failed".

Comment: What I am looking for is a retry policy that allows me to reload the items that failed on demand. Eg: I have a ScrollView that contains KFImages like the one I've presented. Some 'cells' may fail loading the image, other may succed, when user taps a Retry button the failed ones should reload